# Toolbar overlapping status bar after setFlags

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, statusbar, android-fullscreen

My code to set tranparent status bar

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getActivity().getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

after back to home my toolbar is overlapping status bar
[look my toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc4Ut.jpg)

please how to resolve it :(
thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Theme file

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

> **android:fitsSystemWindows**
>
> Boolean internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system
>   windows such as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this
>   view to leave space for the system windows. Will only take effect if
>   this view is in a non-embedded activity.
>
> May be a boolean value, such as "true" or "false".

Answer (score 0):

You can put `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to root view of your activity layout.

This works in my app.